# rspec expect compare two hash that by excluding specified keys

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-hash

Is there any spec expect which will compare two hashes by excluding specified keys alone.

```
H1 = {'name' => 'XXXXx', 'age' => 29, 'DOB' => 'dd/mm/yyyy'}
H2 = {'name' => 'XXXXX', 'age' => 29, 'DOB' => 'dd/mm/yyyy'}
```

Compare the above two hashes by excluding DOB key alone.

Comment: [`Hash#values_at`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) and `match_array` expectation?

Comment: values_at will return an array of values based on the keys specified in values_at. But I want to exclude specific set of keys alone

Comment: `Hash#reject` then.

Comment: Names are different (`"XXXXX"` and `"XXXXx"`)? Or is this typo?

Comment: No it's deliberated. Henceforth I should get a result as Name is differing in H2 when comparing with H1

Comment: Or can anyone suggest me a better solution(or approach) to compare two hashes? Hash may also contain array in value. It would be nice to have the hash in the result which may contain all mismatch keys along with values when comparing H1 with H2

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why do you need so, but you can use [`Hash#delete_if`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html#method-i-delete_if)

```
RSpec.describe do
  let(:hash1) { {'name' => 'XXXXX', 'age' => 29, 'DOB' => 'dd/mm/yyyy'} }
  let(:hash2) { {'name' => 'XXXXX', 'age' => 29, 'DOB' => 'dd/mm/yyyy'} }

  it 'should correctly compare two subhashes' do
    expect(hash1.delete_if { |k,_| k == 'DOB' }).to eql(hash2.delete_if { |k,_| k == 'DOB' })
  end
end
```

If you want to make your `expect` more neatly you can convert hashes before.

Also you can use [`Hash#reject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html#method-i-reject)

```
RSpec.describe do
  it 'should correctly compare two subhashes' do
    hash1 = {'name' => 'XXXXX', 'age' => 29, 'DOB' => 'dd/mm/yyyy'}
    hash2 = {'name' => 'XXXXX', 'age' => 29, 'DOB' => 'dd/mm/yyyy'}
    hash1, hash2 = [hash1, hash2].map { |h| h.reject { |k,_| k == 'DOB' } }

    expect(hash1).to eql(hash2)
  end
end
```

Comment: I think you mistook 'DOB' for 'name'.

Comment: @sawa, thanks. I noticed the names are different (`"XXXXX"` and `"XXXXx"`) and misled myself..

Comment: Wouldn't it be handy to have a hash method `delete2`, such that `{ a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4 }.delete2(:b, :d) #=> { a:1, c:3 }` without mutating the receiver?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Good idea. Looks beautiful. Maybe someday appear in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than comparing two temporary hashes that equal `H1` and `H2` with the key `'DOB'` (if present) removed, one could compare two temporary hashes that have keys `'DOB'` with the same value. That value is arbitrary; I've used `nil`.

```
expect(H1.merge('DOB'=>nil).to eq(H2.merge('DOB'=>nil)))
```

Another way is:

```
expect((H1.keys|H2.keys).all? do |k| 
  k=='DOB' || (H1.key?(k) && H2.key?(k) && H1[k]==H2[k])
end.to eq(true)
```

`H1.key?(k) && H2.key?(k)` is there in case one of the hashes has a key `k` with value `nil` and the other hash does not have a key `k`.

This has the redeeming feature that it has a more modest memory requirement than do the two approaches I mentioned above.

Comment: The assymmetry decreases the beauty. I think you can just merge `{'DOB' => nil}` to both hashes.

Comment: @sawa, agreed. I made the change. Thanks.

Comment: You got to switch the receiver and the argment for merge regarding H1. Otherwise, if H1 had a value for DOB other than nil, ...

Comment: Let's hope I finally have it right. :-) (Note my smileys have noses.)